# Visual Composer editor block tag link css

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I'm trying to insert in a Visual Composer Editor a tag link css like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/website/style.css">
```

but when I save it, the editor remove that. I don't know if the editor of Visual Composer block that.

Any idea ??

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the best place to insert any CSS file is directly in the theme and not on a specific page.

Then, you can insert the classes that the CSS file takes advantage of into the code of Visual Composer.